# Как организовать систему квестов в онлайн-игре?

Tags: php, разработка-игр, online

Ребята, привет.

Короче, на сей раз передо мной встала следующая задача:  
Надо организовать систему квестов в онлайн игре. То есть вручение заданий по достижению какой-либо цели (получил новый LVL или купил какой-нибудь предмет), а также завершение этого задания по достижению какой-либо заданной цели.

В чем вопрос: все данные хранятся в разных таблицах, и каждый раз запускать огромный  foreach по с огроменной цепочкой if-ов не резон вообще, делая 100500 запросов по базе данных. :D

И вот сижу уже который день думаю, как это все организовать? Кто сталкивался с таким уже? Может, есть какие-то статьи на примете? Гугл уже весь облазил, ничего, кроме самих онлайн-игр и тутореалов по созданию квест-игр на flash, не нашел. :( Или, может, есть проекты с открытым кодом на гитхабе? Или объясните в двух словах? Короче, дайте кто что может.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эм, прямо так тяжело на лету тебе сказать, не видя хотя бы структуры БД.
Как это организовать:

```
Таблица "Gamer"
gamer_id
experience
bla
bla

Таблица "Item"
item_id
bla
bla

Таблица "User_item"
user_id
item_id

Таблица "Quest"
quest_id
expirions
item_id
```

И вот тут же простыми LEFT JOIN-ами:

```
Select * from user t1
left join item t2 on t2.user_id=t1.user_id
left join question t3 on t3.expirions=t1.expirions and t3.item_id=t2.item_id
where user_id=$user_id
```

Ну как-то так... Тяжело так ответить. Если долго выполняются вопросы - попробуй memory table использовать.